# cannot display no browser support message

Tags: reactjs, webpack, modernizr, browser-support

Hi my project is working with reactjs and webpack, when loading the website, if running on an old browser which does not support reactjs or webpack, i cant display my browser is not supported message ( i check support with modernizr library). is there a way for me to show a message and use modernizr before they load somehow? maybe somehow use a script that can use modernizr in the html file that loads first? any answer will be welcome! (this needs to work on all browsers). thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly which features you're using and old browser don't support you can do something like optionally load a "polyfills" file.

To achieve something like this you'll first need to create a separate bundle file just for polyfills and you'll have to load them if the browser doesn't support the required features. This last step requires you to have some templating in your html file.

In your webpack entries:

```
polyfills: [
   'babel-polyfill',
   'whatwg-fetch'
]
```

In your plugins:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './index.ejs',
    filename: '../index.html',
    inject: false
})
```

In your index.ejs file:

```
<script>
var newBrowser = (
    'fetch' in window &&
    'Promise' in window &&
    'assign' in Object &&
    'keys' in Object
);

var scripts = [];
if (!newBrowser) {
    scripts.push('<%=htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.polyfills.entry%>');
}

scripts.push('<%=htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.vendors.entry%>');
scripts.push('<%=htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks.app.entry%>');

scripts.forEach(function(src) {
    var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
    scriptEl.src = src;
    scriptEl.async = false;
    document.head.appendChild(scriptEl);
});
</script>
```

Comment: what i want is not to support the browser, just to display a message that i do not support it, my problem is that i cant know i dont support it because i cant use libraries such as modiernizr before my webpack loads